# ¿Como conseguir el último elemento de un puntero de bytes? (C o C++)

Tags: c++, c, punteros

Quiero saber el tamaño de un puntero a bytes.

Estoy probando iterar los elementos del puntero pero no logro atinar cual es el último byte para detener la iteración.

He probado con NULL, nullptr, 0, '\0'... pero nada funciona.

Código ejemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
//------------------------------------------------------------------
struct MyStruct
{
    int myNumber;
    char c[10];
    std::string s;
};
//------------------------------------------------------------------
void DoSomething(char *data)
{
    char* ptr = data;
    int size = 0;

    for (char* it = ptr; it!= nullptr; it++, size++)//<-- no funciona
    {
        std::cout << "size-->" << size << std::endl;
    }
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    MyStruct data;

    std::cout << "size-->" << sizeof(MyStruct) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "size-->" << sizeof(data) << std::endl;
    system("pause");    
    

    DoSomething((char*)&data);
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

PS: No me importa si la solución es en C o C++, lo importante es que funcione.

Gracias!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La memoria está llena de valores indeterminados. No hay ninguna convención que diga que una variable debe terminar en una secuencia de bytes en particular.

El único caso es el de las cadenas de caracteres. Todas deberían estar terminadas en un byte 0 (o carácter nulo).

Para otras cosas, es un error dejar que el for itere sobre valores indeterminados ya que podría leer partes de la memoria que no debería y que el programa crashearía. Es necesario que conozcas el tamaño de lo que estás leyendo.

---

Una forma de transmitir el tamaño de un `struct` es la que emplea la API de Windows: incluyendo un miembro con el tamaño justo al inicio del mismo. [`PROCESSENTRY32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/ns-tlhelp32-processentry32) es un claro ejemplo.

En [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) se puede implementar de la siguiente manera:

```
struct A {
    int tamano = sizeof(A);
    // ...
};

struct B {
    int tamano = sizeof(B);
    // ...
};

struct C {
    int tamano = sizeof(C);
    // ...
};
```

Entonces la posición de memoria de `tamano` coincide con el del `struct` y puedes leer su valor mediante un `int*`. Así:

```
using namespace std;

tuple<int, char*> leerTamano(void* estructura){
    int* ptrTamano = (int*)estructura;
    int tamano = ptrTamano[0] - tamano;
    char* primerByte = (char*)(&ptrTamano[1]);
    return make_tuple(tamano, primerByte);
}

void imprimirEstructura(void* estructura){
    auto [tamano, primerByte] = leerTamano(estructura);

    cout << tamano << " bytes:\n" << hex;
    for (int i = 0; i < tamano; i++)
        cout << (primerByte[i] & 0xFF) << ", ";
}

int main(){
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
    cout << "A ";
    imprimirEstructura(&a);
    cout << "\n\nB ";
    imprimirEstructura(&b);
    cout << "\n\nC ";
    imprimirEstructura(&c);
}
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##fZPLbsIwEEX3/ooRlVDC@yVVagCJoPIF3UFUGWPAKnEix6loK3696dgJJC0FNnEm9x7PnREsjts7xrLsQUh2SDccxiJKtOI0nJKyptP4wKsFEYVUinhKSJoIuQNJQ57ElHFI9MYjBBEp0zCDLwL4E1KDpmiJYAKJ@OTR1pm53uUbxXLv2O8PBsPhaJTXu13odDrkVNL8OzS/oLE9VbC2uMXiFmh@BzR3r1w2/RjFLYtvTOHAuXqxRuc9EpsG8JycKupe0A2IdaFCvGMqbqnzrju4yJe9ANrnhlBSyYZQJUKu/A/NDdXWXKdeevtBIVcc75EQ0jf@aiM4@U2tCgKlJ0JMBhChKQv1fGnxVjaa6giW17AAG6pMpuLDIdoAUaphPD4nxlMN1mhMnlayZl73/Jj3vo2UnRgIs0oPH2cXnptN14qqSKdsYykCqNv9u/aKFtRsSoMLqZBOEWMGxRJ8WOeHOTDvV6O1mfHaRV1Pp07dP@qVXEn/nmP9n2N@z8HMhrLsm20PdJdkbfx7TViz2X/8AQ).

---

En [c](/questions/tagged/c) no puedes darle valores predeterminados a los miembros de un `struct`.

La API de Windows está escrita en C. Por eso la [documentación](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/) pide inicializar un miembro, normalmente llamado `dwSize`, con el tamaño de la estructura.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el ejemplo Mateo

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos cosas distintas.

Una es el puntero, `it` en tu ejemplo. El puntero *apunta* a algo. Su valor es realmente la dirección en la memoria de la computadora. `NULL` o `nullptr` son valores especiales de punteros, que significan que no se apunta a nada. Los demás valores no son nada especial.

Otra cosa es el valor al cual estás apuntando. Se escribe `*it`. Este valor es el contenido de la memoria. `0` es un valor posible, que convencionalmente marca el final de una cadena de caracteres.

Si tu buscas el final de una cadena, es decir un byte (o `char`) con valor 0, debes hacer la comparación con `*it`. Algo como `for(...; *it != 0; ...) { }`